# Probability of getting exactly 4 heads when a coin is tossed 6 times

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I understand that this problem may be elementary, but I'm unable to come up with anything other than this.

1. $n(S)=2^6$

2)number of favorable events $\binom{6}{4}$

thus the probability of desired events is $$\frac{\binom{6}{4}}{2^6}$$
Which is $\frac{15}{64}$

which feels wrong

could someone help, please

Comment: "*which feels wrong*"  Why does that feel wrong?  It is correct (*assuming the coin is fair*)

Comment: it feels unusually low, and as this is my own problem, I have no source other than MSE to verify against. Thanks for verifying my solution!

Comment: If it helps you to feel better about it... write out all of the rest of the possibilities as well.  You can then verify that if you add them all up, you get a total probability of $1$ as expected.  $1+6+15+20+15+6+1=64$

Comment: Let $p(k)$ denote the probability of getting exactly $(k)$ heads in $(6)$ coin tosses, where $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  By your reasoning, you would expect two things to be true:  $$p(k) = \frac{\binom{6}{k}}{2^6}$$ and $$p(0) + p(1) + \cdots + p(6) = 1.$$  Check out the Math, and see if it works.

Comment: In any event, this is a quintessential example of a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  Any introductory book on probability or combinatorics will discuss this at great length.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Yes, I ahve the binomial distribution in my course, but I haven't studied it yet Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @user2661923, I will thanks!

Comment: As one final word of warning... do be careful about "n(S) = ...   and the number of favorable outcomes is n(A)" line of reasoning.  The probability is only found as $\Pr(A)=\dfrac{n(A)}{n(S)}$ in the occasions where it is known in advance that the outcomes in the sample space are equally likely to occur.  It is extremely wrong in many other scenarios.  There are two possibilities when playing the lottery.  You either win, or you lose.  The probability of winning the lottery is not $\frac{1}{2}$ however.  It was fine here since it is known that each outcome with a fair coin are equally likely.

Comment: If the coin were *not* fair, and instead lands on heads with probability $p$... then you must be more careful with your approach.  The correct answer in such a case is found by the binomial distribution to be $\binom{6}{4}p^4(1-p)^2$.  This is despite the fact that even with an unfair coin there are still $2^6$ different possible sequences of coin flips.  The punchline is that those sequences are *not* equally likely with an unfair coin.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt about an exercise, a reasonable mathematical approach is to simplify the exercise data if possible; here, let's look for the probability of getting exactly $2$ heads when a coin is tossed $a=3$ times.
Let's describe this random experience with the sample space $S=\{HHH,HHT,HTH,HTT,THH,THT,TTH,TTT\}$.

By the way, we make sure that $Card(S)=2^a=2^3=8$. The event $A':$"getting exactly $2$ heads" is $A'=\{HHT,HTH,THH\}$. We have$Card(A')=\mathrm{C}_{3}^{2}=\mathrm{C}_{3}^{1}=3$. Suppose that the outcomes in the sample space are equally likely to occur. Then $p(A')=\frac{\mathrm{C}_{3}^{2}}{2^3}=\frac{\mathrm{C}_{3}^{1}}{2^3}$.

So back to our original exercise, and based on what we have learned in our simple case, $p(A)=\frac{\mathrm{C}_{6}^{4}}{2^6}=\frac{\mathrm{C}_{6}^{2}}{2^6}=\frac{\frac{6\times5}{2!}}{2^6}$.